# adding yaxis label in high charts make the x axis ticks to disappear

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am using highcharts.js to generate my graph. Actually , I am formatting time and populating in x-axis ticks and I am giving Y-axis label. when there is single json response both the x-axis ticks and y-axis labels are coming properly but when there is more than a single response x-axis ticks get disbled and y-axis label is coming without any error.\

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 2 * 3600 * 1000,
    min: stime,
    max: etime,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        hour: '%I %p'
    },

    title: {
        text: undefined
    }
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: "Calories History"
    },
    min: 0
},
```

[image]

help me to resolve the issue I want the y-axis label as well as x-axis ticks when there are more resposne in my json response

Comment: Could you paste your json, or replicate exampel as live demo on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Is your picture an example of there being more than one piece of data in the json?

Comment: yes it consists more than one data

Comment: Have you tried the `label.formatter` option to see if this helps (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter)? It may just simply be an issue of the values being too long to render correctly.